# Extracting universal time/atomic time in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am working on a demo app in a flutter in which I want universal date time. I am using `DateTime.now()` but it's giving me devise date and time. Is there any way to get standard/universal date time(America) irrespective of device date-time setup. I want that date-time fetched offline without any connectivity with the internet.

Answer (score 16):

To get universal time use

```
DateTime.now().toUtc()
```

to get local time use

```
someDate.toLocal()
```

There is no support to getting DateTime for a specific locale other than the one your device is located in (configured).
There is at least one package in pub.dartlang.org that provides such a feature though.
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/time_machine looks like it does, but I haven't used it myself yet.

Comment: but gunter UTC time is calculated with respect of device time.I want time irrespective of device time.Means device time plays no role in between.

Comment: There is no way to do that with `DateTime` from Dart core libs. It only knows local time and UTC. You need to use 3rd-party libs to get what you want.

Comment: there is one true time in dart but it requires internet connectivity.

Comment: I don't think it requires internet connectivity. It just needs current date/time and timezone information from the underlying platform (system clock and timezone setting).

Comment: when I implemented the same code (https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/true_time) it gave me an error.

Comment: You fundamentally cannot get the true UTC time without internet connectivity, because there's no way to guarantee the device has the proper time (or timezone) set.